# Baby Rudin exercise 1.6: Is this the proof Rudin expects?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

> $\bf Exercise\, 1.6$
>
> Fix $b>1.$
>
> Prove that if $m,n,p,q$ are integers, $n>0,q>0$ and $r=m/n=p/q$, then
>
> $$
> (b^m)^{1/n}=(b^p)^{1/q}.
> $$

I'm not really sure what I can assume and what  I can't assume, I think that all I need is $(x^y)^z=x^{yz}$ for integers $y,z$, but I'm not sure how to prove this (I don't even know what the expected definition of exponentiation is!).

**Attempt**

$$
\begin{align}
\left((b^m)^{1/n}\right)^n&=b^m\quad \text{By Theorem 1.21 (I think).}\\
\left((b^m)^{1/n}\right)^{nq}&=b^{mq}\quad \text{Here I use $(x^y)^z=x^{yz}$.}\\
\left((b^m)^{1/n}\right)^{nq}&=b^{np}\quad \text{As $mq=np$.}\\
\left((b^m)^{1/n}\right)^{qn}&=b^{pn}\quad 
\end{align}
$$

Then, taking $n$-th and then $q$-th roots, we get our desired result (I think this is possible, again, by theorem $1.21$, but I'm not sure).

Could someone check my proof and tell me which facts about exponentiation we are allowed to assume and use for these kind of proofs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rudin defined $b^n; n \in \mathbb Z$ as *notation* to mean $b^n = b\cdot b ..b$.  Simple grouping allows you to assume $b^nb^m = b \cdot b...b \cdot b\cdot b....b = b^{n+m}$ and $(b^n)^m = b^{nm}$.

By theorem 1.21 you know that for $b^m$ there exists a *unique* $d := (b^m)^{1/n}$ such that $d^n = b^m$.

The excercise is to show if $m/n = p/q$ then $(b^p)^{1/q} = (b^m)^{1/n}$.

Your proof is mostly good.

$((b^p)^{1/q})^{mq} = ([(b^p)^{1/q})^q]^m = ([b^p]^m) = b^{pm}$  So $(b^p)^{1/q} = (b^{pm})^{1/mq}$ which is a uniquely defined number by th 1.21

$((b^m)^{1/n})^{np} = ([(b^m)^{1/n})^n]^p = ([b^m]^p) = b^{pm}$  So $(b^m)^{1/n} = (b^{pm})^{1/np}$ which is a uniquely defined number by th 1.21

But $1/np = 1/mq$ so $(b^{pm})^{1/np} =(b^{pm})^{1/mq}$ are both the same unique number.

So $(b^p)^{1/q} = (b^{pm})^{1/mq} = (b^{pm})^{1/np}= (b^m)^{1/n}$ are all different ways of expressing the same unique number.

Thus defining $b^r$ as $(b^m)^{1/n}$ when $r = m/n$ is consistant, not ambiguous, and always existent.  Thus it is "well-defined".

Answer (score 3):

In general, Rudin seems to assume we know about integers but not reals.  Because of this, it looks like

(a) the definition of $b^i$, with $i$ a positive integer, is inferred from 1.13 ($i$ copies of $b$ multiplied together, just like for the case of $b$ an integer),

(b) $(b^i)^j=b^{ij}$ can be assumed known for positive integers $i, j$ ($j$ copies of $b^i$ multiplied together are the same as $ij$ copies of $b$ multiplied together, say "by associativity"),

(c) similar things can be done for $i$ and $j$ negative, with $b^i$ being $-i$ copies of $1/b$ multiplied together,

(d) from the Corollary to Theorem 1.21 we can also infer $(b^i)^{1/n}=(b^{1/n})^i$ for positive integers $i$ by induction on $i$:  if we assume $(b^i)^{1/n}=(b^{1/n})^i$ already shown for some $i$, let $a=b^i$ in the Corollary; we then get $(b^{i+1})^{1/n}=(b^ib)^{1/n}=(b^i)^{1/n}b^{1/n} =(b^{1/n})^i b^{1/n} = (b^{1/n})^{i+1}$.  From here we can also get the result for $i$ negative.

Assume wlog that $p$ and $q$ have no common divisor.  From our background knowledge regarding integers, we know that $m=jp$, $n=jq$ for some integer $j$.

Our goal is $(b^m)^{1/n}=(b^p)^{1/q}$, that is $(b^{jp})^{1/jq}=(b^p)^{1/q}$. Because of the uniqueness of $n$th roots in Theorem 1.21, we just need to show that $((b^{jp})^{1/jq})^q=b^p$.  Based on (d) above, $$((b^{jp})^{1/jq})^q=(b^{jpq})^{1/jq}=((b^p)^{jq})^{1/jq}=b^p$$ as desired.

It's so much fun to prove stuff with one hand tied behind your back!

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that at this point you have seen the definition for $x^n$ and $x^{1/n}$ where $n\in\mathbb{N}$. The point of the exercise is to show that we can define $x^r$ for rational $r$ in such a way that doesn't depend on any particular representation of $r$.

Let $z=(b^m)^{1/n}$. It's enough to show that $z^q=b^p$. By definition, we have
$$
z^n=b^m\implies z^{nq}=b^{mq}=b^{pn}\implies z^q=b^p
$$
because both equal to the unique $n$-th root of the common value of $z^{nq}=b^{pn}$. Here, we use Theorem 1.21.

The above is very similar to your argument. The difference is in the observation that $z^n=b^m$ doesn't need Theorem 1.21.